# K-means clustering and R - what to do next?

Tags: r, data-mining, k-means

I used `kmeans` command on my data-frame (as suggested in "R and Data Mining: Examples and Case studies"). Now my data is clustered into x number of cluster.
What they don't tell you in this book is what to do next.
How can I get `characteristics` specific for `cluster 1`.
Or how does `cluster 2` differ from `cluster 3`?

Example of my data-frame after clustering.

```
Cluster   Char1   Char2   Char3   Char4   Char4
1         0.00    0.02    1.23    3.21    2.34
1         2.12    12.1    1.42    1.31    2.04
2         5.35    59.2    0.01    9.32    9.33
3         5.23    10.3    8.13    0.72    0.91   
...
```

Is there more informative guide on the internet? How can I investigate these things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have understood your question, what you are looking for is doing [**descriptive statistics**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_statistics) on you data. 
It is the first step of any statistical analysis. And there is huge amount of methods and domains related to it. 
What you will investigate depends only on **what you want to know from your data**.

You can

- calculate moments of your data in each cluster
- study their empirical distribution with histograms, boxplots, goodness-of-fit tests, QQ-plot
- calculate quantiles, probabilities...
- look for dependences between you variables with correlation or kendall's tau
- and a lot more...